# Cannot access array elements using counter from loop

Tags: perl

I am trying to loop through two equally sized arrays, and replace a string with the elements found at each index.

The loop is only doing the first element.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

# SQL statement for string replace
my $insert = "INSERT INTO table ( JOB, URI ) VALUES ( 'JOB', 'URL' );";
#array of jobs
my @jobs = ("job1", "job2");
#array of url's
my @urls = ("http://www.yahoo.com", "http://www.google.com");

# for each job replace the "URL" with a url from 
# the url array, then print the new sql insert statement
for( my $i = 0; $i <= $#jobs; $i++ ){
    $insert =~ s/URL/$urls[$i]/g;
    print $insert."\n";
}
```

EDIT- Using $i<=$#urls now has the correct loop size, but the call  to $urls[$i] never gets a different element in that array. Its always the same element

I think this is an issue with the string replace I am doing, the loop will print out the elements as expected, but not when I use the counter in the string replace.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After the first iteration, `$insert` doesn't content anymore `URI`

change your loop as:

```
for( my $i = 0; $i <= $#jobs; $i++ ){
    my $temp = $insert;
    $temp =~ s/URL/$urls[$i]/g;
    print $temp,"\n";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To answer the issue with the string replace on the insert statement I had, I was trying to change the text in that string, and next loop doing the same search and replace, but there was no longer URL in the string to match on, I should have move that variable to inside the loop.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

#array of jobs
my @jobs = ("job1", "job2");
#array of url's
my @urls = ("http://www.yahoo.com", "http://www.google.com");

# for each job replace the "URL" with a url from 
# the url array, then print the new sql insert statement
for( my $i = 0; $i <= $#jobs; $i++ ){
    # SQL statement for string replace
    my $insert = "INSERT INTO table ( JOB, URI ) VALUES ( 'JOB', 'URL' );";
    $insert =~ s/URL/$urls[$i]/g;
    print $insert."\n";
}
```

Thanks to all who helped.

Answer (score 0):

`$#jobs` get the last index position of last element, `1` in your case. The loop then is from `0` to `0`. Use `@jobs` instead, that get the total number of elements, and would do a loop between `0` and `1`.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this :

```
foreach my $i (0 .. $#jobs) { print "$i\n"; }
```